# Apply with Linkedin Button does not work with Chrome 80?

Tags: google-chrome, linkedin-api, samesite

We have a problem with Linkedin button that we have implemented on our job portal that users can apply directly with their Linkedin account. With the last Chrome Update (80) , users can not login linkedin with script generated button therefore It is not possible to apply with linkedin button. I guess it happens because the script from Linkedin has no samesite attribute. Info: https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie Are you familiar with this Problem? Can you please help me with the problem?

https://s5.gifyu.com/images/Chrome80ApplyWithLinkedin.gif

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message there states that your instance of Chrome is not yet blocking the cookies, so it's unlikely that the `SameSite` attribute is the cause of the issue here. However, you can verify this by taking the following steps.

Check your browser at https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me - if all the rows are green with ✅ then your browser is using the new behaviour.

You can toggle this behaviour on and off via `chrome://flags`. Enter the following in your location bar:

- `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies`
- `chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure`

Set both to "Disabled".

Try your site in an incognito window so that you can be sure there are no old cookies set. If you still receive the error, then this is highly unlikely to be related to the `SameSite` attribute.

I don't know how long ago your initial implementation was, but it does look as if there were some updates to the API at the end of 2018: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/talent/apply-with-linkedin